# TypeScript issue array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

What I'm trying to do is map an array which contains objects with properties and other nested objects to return a React component which I previously imported.

I'm getting this from TypeScript

> Property 'max_temp' does not exist on type 'never'.

> Property 'min_temp' does not exist on type 'never'.

My guess is that TypeScript complains because it doesn't know my array contains nested objects inside so it says I'm never going to get anything calling that.
This is my code (down below I will post a screenshot)

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
type Props = {
  cities: [];
};

const Cards: React.FC<Props> = ({ cities }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {cities.map(({ name, main, weather }) => {
        return (
          <Card
            name={name}
            max={main.max_temp}
            min={main.min_temp}
            img={weather[0].icon}
            onClose={() => alert({ name })}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Cards;
```

[image]

Comment: There are [971 hits searching for that error message on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Property+does+not+exist+on+type+%27never%27). Do none of those answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to type your cities array, e.g. something like that (your props of `Card` may require actually different types):

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
type Props = {
  cities: [
    { name: string, 
      main: {
         max_temp: number, 
         min_temp: number
      }, 
      weather: Array<{icon: any}> 
    }];
};

const Cards: React.FC<Props> = ({ cities }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {cities.map(({ name, main, weather }) => {
        return (
          <Card
            name={name}
            max={main.max_temp}
            min={main.min_temp}
            img={weather[0].icon}
            onClose={() => alert({ name })}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Cards;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the type of cities in Props.

```
type Props = {
  cities: []; <--- what is this array of?
};
```

for example:

```
type Props = {
  cities: CityType[];
};
```